How can I calculate $\chi(\mathscr{O}(P))$
Let be X a reduced and irreducible curve over a field $L_0$. Let $L$ an extension of $L_0$ and set
\begin{gather*}
\overline{X}=L \otimes X.
\end{gather*}
Assume $\overline{X}$ also irreducible. Now, let $P_0 \in X$ be a regular closed point and set $P=L \otimes P_0$. If $\mathscr{O}_{\overline{X}}(P)$ is the ideal sheaf of $P$, how can I calculate $\chi(\mathscr{O}_{\overline{X}}(P))$? I do not really know much of sheaf cohomology, so any comment will be really helpful to me.
Thanks!
